# How to bind to property of object returned by converter

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'm trying to bind to a value, run a converter over it, and then display a property of that value. Having the Converter directly return the property I want wouldn't work, as I need property changes to be tracked.

What I'm trying to achieve would be something like this:

```
// NOTE: FOLLOWING IS NOT SUPPORTED BY WPF
// A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'Source' property of type 'Binding'.
// A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.

Text={Binding TextField Source={Binding SomeValue, Converter={StaticResource GetObjectFromValueConverter}}}`
```

Ideally, this would all be wrapped up in a simple markup extension.

`Text={l:GetTextField SomeValue}`

Problem is, I haven't been able to find any way to do this other than bind the `Tag` of the element to the converter, and then bind the target field to the property as follows:

```
Tag={Binding SomeValue, Converter={StaticResource GetObjectFromValueConverter}}
Text={Binding Tag.TextField, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}
```

This is obviously cumbersome, limited (you only get one `Tag` field) and feels abusive. How else can I go about achieving what I want whilst monitoring for changes of `TextField` though?

Answer (score 3):

You can bind the `DataContext` of the `TextBox`, instead of the `Tag`. That will make your other bindings much simpler:

```
DataContext="{Binding SomeValue, Converter={StaticResource GetObjectFromValueConverter}}"
Text="{Binding TextField}"
```

This assumes that you do not have any other bindings on the `TextBox` that require the inherited `DataContext`. For example, in the bindings below `Text2` would be broken:

```
DataContext="{Binding SomeValue, Converter={StaticResource GetObjectFromValueConverter}}"
Text2="{Binding SomeOtherValue, Converter={StaticResource GetObjectFromValueConverter}}"
Text="{Binding TextField}"
```

Also, if you have a more complex control other than `TextBox`, the `DataContext` for any controls below it in the logical/visual tree will also be affected.

Comment: This of course assumes that you don't have other bindings to your outer DataContext, but as long as that's the case is a good solution.

Comment: But what if I want to bind Text to one object->converter->property and TextWrapping to another? Use DataContext for one and Tag (referencing the previous DataContext through RelativeSource FindAncestor) for another? Seems awfully hackish.. what if I want 3?

Comment: @Mania - Yeah, unfortunately when you start mixing things like that you either have to use Tag or a custom converter. You don't show what GetObjectFromValueConverter is doing, but things like "MyObject.SomeValue" are valid ways to get sub-properties.